# Basic node.js - variable and Mongoose scope

Tags: node.js, mongoose

the console.log(workingWeekdaysVar) line; is outside the findOne's scope, and the variable was declared outside it too,  yet it's giving me null ...

when i put   console.log(workingWeekdaysVar); inside the findOne's scope, it does give the right output, but this is useless for me because I wanna use workingWeekdaysVar elsewhere below.

The two commented out lines are the 2nd approach i attempted to do, but it gave me an undesirable output because this whole code is inside a complicated for loop.

How can I simply pass the fetched value of workingWeekdaysVar out of the scope?

```
    var workingWeekdaysVar = [];

                    buyerSupplierFisModel.findOne(filter).then(function (combo) {

                        workingWeekdaysVar = combo.workingWeekdays;

                         //server.getWorkingWeekdays = function () { return combo.workingWeekdays };

                    });

   console.log(workingWeekdaysVar);

//console.log(server.getWorkingWeekdays());
```

Answer (score 1):

`findOne()` is an asynchronous function (it returns a promise object). This means that it returns inmediately and your next code line is run (in this case, `console.log(workingWeekdaysVar);`. But, since the function isn't done yet, `workingWeekdaysVar` is empty, and it will be empty until `findOne()` has done its job and returned the results in the provided chained callback `.then(function (combo) {...`.

So if you want to do anything with the results, you'll have to do it in the callback. One option to this would be to use `async / await`:

```
(async () => {
    try {
        const { workingWeekdaysVar } = await buyerSupplierFisModel.findOne(filter)
        console.log(workingWeekdaysVar)
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`Error: ${e}`);
    }
})()
```

Answer (score 0):

Re-arranging your code  a bit:

```
let doToResponse = (combo)=>{
 workingWeekdaysVar = combo.workingWeekdays; 
 console.log(workingWeekdaysVar);
}
 buyerSupplierFisModel.findOne(filter).then(function (combo) {
                        doToResponse(combo)
                    });
```

- good for re-usability

My personal favorite:

```
buyerSupplierFisModel.findOne(filter).then(combo=> {
    workingWeekdaysVar = combo.workingWeekdays; 
    console.log(workingWeekdaysVar);
});
```

The important thing is keep in mind, as Miguel Calderón says.. findOne - returns a promise.  At that point you have another thread with different local (Lexical?) scope